# Customization of hook function

Tags: drupal

I Am new to drupal I need to customize core functionality like register module and event module.please share you thought / sample code / sample website for get the clarification over my issue

Thanks in advance
Balaji

Comment: First of all the event module is not part of drupal core and there is no register module, are you thinking about the signup module?
Anyways can you be a bit more precise as to what it is you want to do. You can't change hooks as your title implies as they are used by other modules so doing that would break other parts most likely.

Answer (score 1):

From what you posted in the comment to creejayoz answer, it seems like what you are after is not using hook_form_alter, but something in the line of what the profile module does. It's part of drupal core, and with it you can add extra fields to the user like first and last name. There are also more advanced modules that you can use instead, but it seems like you wont need it. Using the profile module will also be a lot quicker and easier than using hook_form_alter as you wont need to create a db table make SQL and such to the save the data.

Comment: Yep, `profile.module` is the way to go here. No coding needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_form_alter` to heavily modify the way Drupal's registration works, by modifying the form's fields, adding extra validation/submit functions, etc. It's difficult to give more detail without knowing what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz,
I just want to add some more fields like firstname,lastname.. on registration page.and also i need to make sure to view / edit the those information under the my account section.